# Mapping MySQL ENUM with AttributeConverter in InheritanceType.JOINED throwing IllegalArgumentExceptionon Hibernate 5.3.6 (JPA 2.1+): No enum constant

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, orm

I am mapping an inheritance hierarchy as shown here:

[image]

The thing here is, that the DB contains the single-char ENUM values 'P', 'C', and 'A' for persons, clubs and arenas respectively, but the Java enum values to work with are supposed to be PERSON, CLUB and ARENA.

This requires an `AttributeConverter` to be used to perform the DB value - Java enum conversion (see mappings below):

Contact entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contacts")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Contact extends BaseIdEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    protected Integer id;

    @Convert(converter=ContactTypeConverter.class)  // <-- !!! ... see below
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column
    protected ContactType type;  // actually a discriminator, but for JOINED inheritance, it is not required to annotate the class with @DiscriminatorColumn

    ...
}
```

ContactType ENUM:

```
public enum ContactType
{
    PERSON,  <-- fully written, but data is single-char
    CLUB,
    ARENA;
}
```

Person entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Persons")
public class Person extends Contact
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    ...
}
```

Club entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Clubs")
public class Club extends Contact
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column
    private String code;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="website_url")
    private String websiteUrl;

    ...
}
```

Arena entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Arenas")
public class Arena extends Contact
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column
    private Integer capacity;

    ...
}
```

Attribute converter for `ContactType`:

```
@Converter( autoApply = false )
public class ContactTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ContactType, String>
{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn( ContactType contactType )
    {
        System.out.println( "convertToEntityAttribute(" + contactType + ")" );

        switch ( contactType )
        {
            case PERSON:
                return "P";

            case CLUB:
                return "C";

            case ARENA:
                return "A";

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown enum value: " + contactType );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ContactType convertToEntityAttribute( String value )
    {
        System.out.println( "convertToEntityAttribute(\"" + value + "\")" );

        switch ( value )
        {
            case "P":
                return PERSON;

            case "C":
                return CLUB;

            case "A":
                return ARENA;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown DB value: " + value );
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the DDL + data for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contacts`(
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` ENUM('P', 'C', 'A') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `Arenas` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `arenas_contacts_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `Contacts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE `Clubs` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `website_url` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `clubs_contacts_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `Contacts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `persons_contacts_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `Contacts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO `Contacts` (`id`, `type`) VALUES
(  1, 'P'),
(  2, 'P'),
(  3, 'P'),
( 26, 'P'),
( 99, 'P'),
(101, 'C'),
(102, 'C'),
(103, 'C'),
(201, 'A'),
(202, 'A'),
(203, 'A');

INSERT INTO `Persons` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(  1, 'Kay', 'Wundrak'),
(  2, 'Joe', 'Locke'),
(  3, 'Ahmed', 'Thiab'),
( 26, 'Seb', 'Gottwalk'),
( 99, 'Test', 'Test');

INSERT IGNORE INTO `Clubs` (`id`, `name`, `code`) VALUES
(101, 'TV Dieburg', 'DIEB'),
(102, 'SC Rist Wedel', 'RIST'),
(103, 'BBG Herford', 'HERF');

INSERT IGNORE INTO `Arenas` (`id`, `name`, `capacity`) VALUES
(201, 'Schlossgartenhalle', NULL),
(202, 'Steinberghalle', NULL),
(203, 'Halle am Gymnasium', NULL);
```

I have consulted many sources, e.g.

https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html [MAIN]

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

http://eloquentdeveloper.com/2016/07/18/persisting-enums-using-jpa-attribute-converter/

All say the same, but it doesn't work. When loading a list of persons I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant net.bbstats.entity.ContactType.P
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.fromName(EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.NamedEnumValueConverter.toDomainValue(NamedEnumValueConverter.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.NamedEnumValueConverter.readValue(NamedEnumValueConverter.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3007)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1746)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.Repository.findByNamedQuery(Repository.java:184)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:382)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:368)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:344)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findAllByQueryWithFetchGraph(BaseEntityService.java:300)
    ... 179 more
```

Look at line:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant net.bbstats.entity.ContactType.P`

Not really converting correctly or not at all...?

**QUESTION:**

What's wrong here? I am nearly 100% sure, that the mappings are correct...

-> **Is it a Hibernate bug?** Is it because of the inheritance mappings? Maybe not working with `InheritanceType.JOINED`?

In any case, one observation is, that no matter what, the attribute converter is **never called**, that is no breakpoints are ever reached in `ContactTypeConverter` and no sysouts are ever printed to the console/log.

Setup: WildFly 14.0.1.Final, Hibernate 5.3.6.Final

Comment: Could you please try to remove `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` from `Contact.type`.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Amazing. But I don't really understand why. OK, the `@Convert` seems to be a replacement for `@Enumerated` then? Is this defined anywhere in the spec? Yuck yuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums-attribute-converter).

> JPA explicitly disallows the use of an `AttributeConverter` with an attribute marked as `@Enumerated`. So, when using the `AttributeConverter` approach, be sure not to mark the attribute as `@Enumerated`.